# Looking for a way to break up a string with multiple \n and turn it into innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have been writing JavaScript since yesterday and am brand new at it.

I have a string that I am breaking up and turning into input for a table.  The entries are separated by '\n' like 'a\nb', which indicates the need for a new row between a and b.

The current code that I have works for a single instance of '\n', but it quit working when it was back to back entries, specifically "1.1\n2.1\n3.1\n4.1\n".

It has worked with other examples that are comma separated, such as "a,b,c\n1,2,3", "1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5\n", and "1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5\n2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5\n3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5\n4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5\n".  Because some inputs are comma separated, it must work with those as well as with the input that is separated by '\n'.

My method up to this point has been to split the string into an array, and then search the index of the array to see if it contains the '\n'.  If it does, I split the array at the '\n', and splice it with two entries instead of one.  I then set a variable indicating that I need to go to the next row, which moves into an if else if right below.

```
var functionCreate = function (strInput) {

            var array = strInput.split(",");

            var html = "<table border=1><tr>";

            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var newL = false;
                if (array[i].indexOf("\n") >= 0) {
                    newL = true;
                    newStr = array[i].split("\n");
                    array.splice(i, 1, newStr[0]);
                    array.splice(i + 1, 0, newStr[1]);
                }
                if (newL === true) {
                    html += "<td>" + array[i] + "</td></tr>";
                }
                else if (array[i]) {
                    html += "<td>" + array[i] + "</td>"
                }
            }

            html += "</table>"
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
```

What I output currently is:

```
output: "<table border=\"1\"><tbody><tr><td>1.1</td></tr><tr><td>2.1</td></tr></tbody></table>"
```

And my expected is:

```
"<table border=\"1\"><tbody><tr><td>1.1</td></tr><tr><td>2.1</td></tr><tr><td>3.1</td></tr><tr><td>4.1</td></tr></tbody></table>"
```

The 3.1 and 4.1 are getting cut off, which is understandable because I believe everything trailing the 2.1 is in i + 1 of newStr.

Does anyone have any idea how to get past this?  Is there a way to split it at only the first '\n' and run the through the loop again until there are no more newlines?

Comment: no clue what the whoel comma thing is at the start but like this : array[i].split('\n').forEach((numberString)=>{html+="<tr><td>"+numberString+"</td></tr>"}) basically split at \n and add all entries to html (kinda weird since you already used the split function a few lines before that oO)

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are inputs that are comma separated as well.  It must work for both.  I added the previous inputs that worked successfully in the beginning of the post for clarification.  Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: I think the right order is `split \n` after `split ,` and take the first index => 1.1, 2.1, 3.1...

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`var array = strInput.split(",");` 
to
`var array = strInput.split("\n");`

Comment: There is comma separated input as well, so this won't work.  I edited my original post to show previously entered input.  Thank you though!